# Can't try to realize to take random results from query to Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a database on Firestore, there are some data. Have a ListView, where I put 3 random records, which I try put of all records in database, that I request in query. But with launch, listview is empty. What is the problem?

My Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placeRef = rootRef.collection("Peoples");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    placeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Peoples> peoplesList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Peoples peoples = document.toObject(Peoples.class);
                    peoplesList.add(peoples);
                }
                if (peoplesList.size() > 0) {
                    int placeCount = peoplesList.size();
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    List<Peoples> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomPlaceList.size());
                        Peoples item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex);
                        randomPlaceList.add(item);
                    }
                    ListView mListView = findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                    PeoplesAdapter peoplesAdapter = new PeoplesAdapter(getBaseContext(), randomPlaceList);
                    mListView.setAdapter(peoplesAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class PeoplesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Peoples> {
    public PeoplesAdapter(Context context, List<Peoples> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        Peoples peoples = getItem(position);
        Log.d("TAG", peoples.getName());
        String name = peoples.getName();
        ((TextView) listItemView).setText(name);

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

And Model class:

```
class Peoples {
private String name, age;

public Peoples() {}

public Peoples(String name, String age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

}

The example of my Firestore database:

[image]

One time it's work, but just one..

Comment: Could you debug to see if `peoplesList` has any data?

Comment: there are no data@MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: I try `log` and debug - but nothing, I think that problem in Firestore, but when connect to it other class - all good.@MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lying here:

```
int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomPlaceList.size());
```

`Random::nextInt(0)` will throw exceptions.

While you init your `randomPlaceList` as

```
List<Peoples> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>(); // size = 0
```

So I think the correct random function should be:

```
int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount); // placeCount = peopleList.size()
Peoples item = peoplesList.get(randomIndex);
```

Comment: the same result@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: Check your `peoples` loading. Place debug here `Peoples peoples = document.toObject(Peoples.class);` to see if it hit.

Comment: Sorry for question. Like this Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(peoples));@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn ?

Comment: Nothing..@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: Check for firebase dude

Comment: With Firestore all good, I put in this info in ReycleView, and all good, just without random@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: Please use `System.out.println(peoplesList)` just before the `if (peoplesList.size() > 0)` too see if it output anything

Comment: `I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0`    `I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:30000`   `I/System.out: [socket][0] connection api.accuweather.com/23.64.226.207:443;LocalPort=34678(30000)`   `I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:30000` @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: Check this line `CollectionReference placeRef = rootRef.collection("Peoples");`. Firebase API is case sensitive, your firebase collection name is `peoples`. Try to rename it and check if it helps, dudde

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.arara.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:46)`   in this line: Peoples item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex);
@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: It should be:  `Peoples item = peoplesList.get(randomIndex);`

Comment: Yessss!!!! It work. But 2 days later, it's work too, and after reboot PC, it's got me an error. Hope this the last time! Thank man!@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn